# Lucene query with both wildcard and NOT

Tags: lucene

I try to run a Lucene query to include some dates and exclude some dates.
But I notice that combination wildcards and NOT seems dose not work. I checked the query syntax and searched sometime in the internet, but got no luck. Am I missing anything? My request is to get the other dates of the month except first day. And my query is as below:

```
(field1:foo*) AND (field2:2019-* NOT 2019-*-01)
```

And the query without NOT works:

```
(field1:foo*) AND (field2:2019-09-*)
```

Comment: What is the fieldtype of field2 ?

Comment: hi, you may have the point, this is the usage of a plugin in a service, and the filed2 is the data source from a json file, so I do not know how dose the service define the type of the field2. And I just treat field2 as string.

Comment: Could you try this query?
(field1:foo*) AND (field2:2019-* NOT field2:2019-*-01)